# How could I save the new server name with an guildUpdate with mongoose? | discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, discord.js

How can I replace the oldguild(old server's name) to a new one when server updated?  I tried with GuildID(discord server id) and everything but nothing seem to work. When the bot saves it, then looks like this in the MongoDB Compass:  [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3HzNz.jpg), and for example this is how it looks like in MongoDB Compass normally: [Old name server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PaGdj.jpg), but I want it look like this [New name server](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MgFYN.jpg).

This is my code.

```
client.on("guildUpdate", (oldguild, newguild) => {
        var name = [oldguild.name, newguild.name];

        if(name[0] == null) {
          name[0] = oldguild.name
        }
        if(name[1] == null) {
          name[1] = oldguild.name
        }

        if(oldguild.name !== newguild.name)
        {
          async function guildUpdated() {
            const servername = new setprefixModel ({
              _id: mdb.Types.ObjectId(),
              GuildID: setprefixModel.GuildId,
              Guild: oldguild.name,
              Prefix: setprefixModel.Prefix
            });
            const reqservername = await setprefixModel.findOne({ Guild: oldguild.name });
            if(!reqservername) {
              return await servername.save();
            }
            else {
             const updatedDocument = await setprefixModel.findOneAndUpdate(
               { Guild: oldguild.name },
               { Guild: newguild.name },
               { new: true }
             );
            updatedDocument;
            }
           }
          guildUpdated();
        }
      })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
client.on("guildUpdate", (oldguild, newguild) => {
        var name = [oldguild.name, newguild.name];

        if(name[0] == null) {
          name[0] = oldguild.name
        }
        if(name[1] == null) {
          name[1] = oldguild.name
        }

        if(oldguild.name !== newguild.name)
        {
          async function guildUpdated() {
            const servername = new setprefixModel ({
              _id: mdb.Types.ObjectId(),
              GuildID: String,
              Guild: oldguild.name,
              Prefix: String
            });
            const reqservername = await setprefixModel.findOne({ Guild: oldguild.name });
            if(!reqservername) {
              return await servername.save();
            }
            else {
             const updatedDocument = await setprefixModel.findOneAndUpdate(
               { Guild: oldguild.name },
               { Guild: newguild.name },
               { new: true }
             );
            updatedDocument;
            }
           }
          guildUpdated();
        }
      })
```

Changed at `const servername`.